# Python - Copying Multiple Files Within Directory

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I am new to Python and attempting to write an automated testing program. More specifically, I am trying to copy several .xlsx files from one directory to another. I've researched pretty thoroughly and am partially there. My code is below, which does not return and errors, but does not accomplish what I am trying to do. I believe my code is not granular enough (I am getting stuck at the directory level). In a nutshell: File A contains c, d, e, f.1, f.2, f.3 (all Excel docs). File B is empty. I am trying to copy f.1, f.2, and f.3 into File B. I believe I need to add the startswith function at some point, too. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

source = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a'
dest1 = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b'

src_files = os.listdir('C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a')

for file_name in src_files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join('C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a','a') #'a' incorrect
    if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, dest1)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the variables `source` and `dest1`:

```
source = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a'
dest1 = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b'

src_files = os.listdir(source)

for file_name in src_files:
    if not file_name.startswith('f'):
        continue
    src = os.path.join(source, file_name)  # <--
    dst = os.path.join(dest1, file_name)   # <--
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thank you. That copied all of the files. I would like to just copy the ones beginning with 'f' and will eventually rename them in the destination file.

Comment: I'm assuming I need an if statement specifying the startswith

Comment: @AndrewC10, I updated the code in the answer to skip files whose name does not starts with `f`.